# Jquery ajax - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I'm using the following code, but when it runs Chrome shows 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    url: "local.php",   
    success: function(data) {
        console.log (data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log (data)
    }
});
```

I'm connecting to the server and accessing pages via https, the ajax request is going to the same server so the page requests are local.

Is there anyway to stop this happening ?

Thanks

Comment: 1) use http not https so it doesn't need a cert, *or* 2) give your server a valid cert

Comment: There seem to be plenty of [solutions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID+localhost) - perhaps one of them will match your requirement (eg enable `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`)

Comment: Thanks, I've been checking the server this is running on and when I access it via HTTPS I am seeing an invalid certificate warning.. I guess that won't help !